# Formatting Issues with Excel Interop using C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop

I have a C# application that uses an existing Excel spreadsheet as a template and fills in data.  In the template there is a blank row that has some style formatting such as font/border and data formatting such as currency and percentages.  When filling in the data from the application I copy this row *n* times and fill in the data.  The style formatting works but as far as the data formatting it doesn't apply until I open up the spreadsheet click on the column then off of it.  Does this have something to do with Excel interpreting the values as just string data and not being able to format it?  Am I stuck with having to do my data formatting in the application?

Comment: Can you post some code? I'm not sure I completely understand what you're doing.

Comment: -1 because it is yet another incomplete, yet interesting, but abandoned question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try explicitly formatting each row after populating it.  Is this Excel 2003 or 2007?